# "The map has changed since the iterator was created" in Chrome sender app

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I'm seeing this error and I'm not sure where it's coming from.  I am using cast v3 sdk in Chrome, the call stack includes cast_sender.js `onMessage` function. I believe it is happening after the receiver issues a `broadcastStatus` media message.

Has anyone seen this error message in the web console: `"The map has changed since the iterator was created"`?

Comment: This happens to me when trying to requestSessionById after the being notified that receiver is available. I've still havent figured it out.

Comment: If you can reproduce, file an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc

Comment: @Leon Nicholls I filed 2 issues. (Sorry)
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141903675
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/143015206
(Wanted to include some extra info, but couldn't comment, so I created another issue, and found out I can't delete either.  Sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me in the following code:

```
session.addUpdateListener(function listener (isAlive) { 
    // This is what causes the error
    session.removeUpdateListener(listener);
});
```

It only happens when I have `session.removeUpdateListener(listener);`
I guess it's unhappy that I removed the listener.

Maybe it is the same kind of thing for you?